# Почему не устанавливается клиент-серверное соединение?

Tags: python, сокет

Есть следующие скрипты на Python:
Для клиента:

```
from socket import *
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverName = #IP
serverPort = 9090

message = str.encode(input('Input your lowercase message:'))
clientSocket.sendto(message, (serverName,serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddr = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print (modifiedMessage)
clientSocket.close()
```

Для сервера:

```
from socket import * 
serverPort = 9090
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
print ('The server is ready for the message')

while True:
    message, clientAddr = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    modifiedMessage = message.upper()
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddr)
```

По отдельности на каждом их хостов части программы запускаются, но не взаимодействуют. Строку заглавными буквами получить так и не удалось. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: А почему используете именно SOCK_DGRAM?

Comment: UDP не устанавливает соединения в принципе. Поправьте заголовок